# android CoordinatorLayout layout_anchor not showing properly

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, layout-anchor

I am working on this from 2 days but still not getting how to fix this, In CoordinatorLayout only **FloatingActionButton** is properly anchoring but i want to apply anchor on **"View"** layout, i've worked so far but view is hiding half of view behind toolbar... Please help ..Thanks in Advance

[image]

here is Layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.rvsoftcorp.zetaride.MainActivity">
   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar">
           <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            android:alpha="0.9"></android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
  <View
    android:id="@+id/ntb_sample_5"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/
```

Comment: Post full code of your layout please.

Comment: try this...  `yourView.bringToFront();`

Comment: add elevation to your view; 6dp for example.

Answer (score 0):

View ntb_sample should be an `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton`